# How do I update my thingspeak channel using MIT app inventor

Tags: android

I am looking to update my thingspeak channel with custom values from the app I am building with mit app inventor 2. Till now I am able to send fixed values. But cannot update the channel with user inputs.
Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Can someone start tagging questions for ThingSpeak with a "thingspeak" tag. It would help discover these questions and get answers quicker. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the design screen, add a TextBox named Input and a Button named Send. You also need to add a Web Connectivity element and assign it to the Url: https://api.thingspeak.com/update

On the Blocks screen, use the "PostTextWithEncoding" block when the button is clicked. Pass in the text of the update, "api_key=YLT2AAO8ZIT4R13Z&field1=" and the input box Text. The encoding should be set to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded".

Here's what the blocks look like: [image]

Let me know if you need further help. It is tricky to explain since I can't share the app code.

Comment: Hey! Thanks I got it!